# Entity Framework split string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Outside of the main model I am building this list which I am them adding to a the main model that the method is returning. I wanted to know if I can do all this work inside building the main model?

Before building the main model

```
string Territorystring = (from p in db.Projects
                          join pm in db.ProjectMaterialUses on p.ProjectId equals pm.ProjectId
                          where projectId == p.ProjectId
                          select pm.Territory).FirstOrDefault();

List<string> guidStrings = TerritoryOfDistributionList.Split(',').ToList();

List<Guid> guids = guidStrings.Select(Guid.Parse).ToList();

List<Model.Country> = (from co in db.vwCountryItemDictionaries
                       where guids.Contains(co.CountryGUID)
                       select new Model.Country
                                  {
                                      Name = co.Name
                                  }).ToList();
```

Main model

```
select new Project                                               
{
    TerritoryOfDistributionList = TerritoryOfDistributionList,
    .....
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell what you're doing, no; avoid having CSV in a column - do it via a supported method that works on a DB such as putting them in their own table that is 1:M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your list is used client-side, I'm assuming it will be in the form of an array.  If that's true, then you could always switch your csv over to a json array (assuming your territory links aren't expecting to change):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

If the territory links are expected to change, you could always do version-chaining/updates via bulk sql statements.

Alternatively, you could set up a view, and read against that instead.